# In beta sites, link to Site Stats on Stack Exchange leads just to list of sites

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, beta-sites, site-stats

Each beta site has such box in the right sidebar of the homepage:

> [image]

Expected behavior when clicking "stack exchange" is the list of sites displayed and auto scrolled to the relevant site, or if grid view then the relevant site will auto expand itself.

Observed behavior: it's just showing the list of sites and that's it.

The link raw URL is something like `http://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#movies` so it looks like it used to work before and got broken at some point. (no named anchors anymore)

Comment: Any news about this bug?

Comment: @BlasSoriano you're asking the wrong person, I'm just ordinary user who reported the bug, can't tell if the team even saw this. :/

Comment: I was going to ask the same question, but found yours (so I tried to avoid a duplicate). However it is an old question, with no answers... I wonder if I can do anything besides asking it again.

Comment: Yes, starting a bounty - which I just did.