# Link to Stack Exchange in Site Stats doesn't work properly

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, site-stats

Similar to [Link from beta sites to Stack Exchange stats is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291965/link-from-beta-sites-to-stack-exchange-stats-is-broken) and [In beta sites, link to Site Stats on Stack Exchange leads to hot questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209752/295232); but right now it's different; it seems to lead to the right page, the site list/grid on stackexchange.com, but the wrong part of the page.

Example: [Sports Stack Exchange](https://sports.stackexchange.com):

[image]

The formatting is broken due to the [new theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315711/295232), but the link, https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#sports, is broken as well. Depending on whether I'm logged in or not, it either leads to https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#oldest:

[image]

or to https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#:

[image]

but in neither of the cases, the Sports site is scrolled to or selected.